# How much time do I have to wait before I can sell another car?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I was wondering: How much time does it take until the cooldown resets and I can sell another car in the GTA Online LS Customs Garage?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

48 minutes real time, which equals one day in game.
The timer also continues running when you play singleplayer or go offline.

Comment: Any source about this fact ?

Comment: A source would be very nice, because I think there are other conditions.

Comment: In my experience this answer is true. But then again I only sell cars that are worth 8000$ or more, so I don't know if that might be a factor for the time limit.

Answer (score 1):

Although @sdfghjk's (that's a mouthful!) [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/133518/130645) is accurate, let me provide some more information:

You can sell a car to Los Santos Customs once per in-game day, which is every 48 minutes. Note that you **always** need to wait an entire 48 minutes between selling cars, so if you sold one at 9:03pm on one day, you couldn't then sell another car at 1am the next day: you would need to wait until 9:03pm. All servers are synced to the same in-game time, and that time elapses regardless of whether people are logged in (although I can't comment for what happens if the servers go down).

[GTA Wiki (not an entirely credible source)](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Time):

> GTA Online's time will correspond to every player in the session so if the time is 22:00 in one player's game, it will be the same for every other player.
>
> Time is live in GTA Online, so leaving the game, and returning 10 minutes later will result in GTA Online's time being progressed by 5 hours. Again, this applies to all players, and all sessions; all sessions will be the same time.

and [another wiki page](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Los_Santos_Customs_Vehicle_Prices):

> Players can only sell a vehicle once per day (in-game) or 48 minutes in real-time.

[IGN](http://au.ign.com/wikis/gta-5/How_to_Make_Money_in_GTA_Online):

> you can only sell one car per in-game day (48 minutes).

I can also confirm from playing the game through Steam (I cannot link to my profile as I didn't purchase the game through Steam, but I added it to my library) that this is accurate. I do my best to sell cars as often as I can, and it's often the first thing I do upon joining and if I forget to track the time (either via ESC or checking my in-game phone) I check the Steam overlay and see how long I've been playing.